# Swift Class in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have settings.swift and i am importing -Swift.h into my ObjC class .m file. I need something like :

@property(nonatomic, strong) Settings *settings; 
but -Swift.h must be imported in .m file and .h does not know anything about settings.swift. Do you have idea how to do this ?

Comment: is your project objective-c or swift based ?

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: There isn't enough info here to help out. Try searching for "mixing swift code with objective-c code" and you'll find a few links that will help you understand this better.

Comment: @enzo Objective C

Comment: @xdeleon i understand this process but i can use swift classes only in .m file that I can not do the property of Swift Class Type and refer to it from other classes such as inherit.

Comment: declare @class Settings; in the Objective-C header.

Comment: @Cosyn Yea ! I did it yesterday and it works. Thanks for your Answer :) If you want add it like normal answer and i will give you mark